# Time difference between events within one device in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google Analytics and BigQuery. I have events reported by applications.

```
Data
vendor_id | event_name | source (from event_params) | event_timestamp
1         | check      | source_1                   | 2022-11-20 08:49:44.322000
2         | check      | source_1                   | 2022-11-21 04:49:44.322000
1         | check      | source_2                   | 2022-11-20 06:49:44.322000
1         | check      | source_2                   | 2022-11-23 04:49:44.322000
2         | check      | source_1                   | 2022-11-15 01:49:44.322000
2         | check      | source_1                   | 2022-11-25 08:49:44.322000
1         | check      | source_2                   | 2022-11-10 02:49:44.322000
```

How can I calculate median/average time difference between event_timestamp within one device among each source? Using BigQuery only.

Expected output:

```
vendor_id | event_name | source (from event_params) | median      | average
1         | check      | source_1                   | 250 seconds | 350 seconds
1         | check      | source_2                   | 400 seconds | 850 seconds 
2         | check      | source_1                   | 950 seconds | 650 seconds 
2         | check      | source_2                   | 850 seconds | 850 seconds
```

Comment: Basically you want the median/average between the event_timestamps of the same vendor_id, event_name and source?

Comment: @dnnshssm yes. But event_name is already the same.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using window functions to get the next timestamp of a given vendor_id, event_name and source and then calculate the average:

```sql
WITH calc_next_event_timestamp AS (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    LEAD(event_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_id, event_name, source ORDER BY event_timestamp) as next_event_timestamp
  FROM sample
)
SELECT
  vendor_id,
  event_name,
  source,
  AVG(DATETIME_DIFF(next_event_timestamp, event_timestamp, SECOND)) AS average
FROM calc_next_event_timestamp 
GROUP BY vendor_id, event_name, source
```

Comment: Will it calculate the average between two timestamps or between all timestamps?

Comment: @Vladislav what do you mean with "average between two timestamps"? This query will calculate the seconds between two events and then calculate an average duration by vendor_id, event_name and source.

Comment: I need to calculate the average between all events, not just two.